# Alias in class method and global function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to encapsulate winsock2 inside a class, and I have this member function called `bind`, which obviously bumps into winsock2.h 's `bind` function.

```
class foo {
public:
  void bind();
  void some_function() {
    bind(_sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen); //error... compiler actually calls foo::bind() instead of the global bind function.
  }

private:
  ...
}
```

Is there a solution for this? (aside from renaming `foo::bind()`).

Comment: `::bind(....)`.

Comment: @songyuanyao you should convert that to an answer!

Comment: Slightly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423474/socket-binding-wont-return-an-int

Comment: @Curious The question is not 100% clear, and I'm not 100% sure whether this is the solution. (BTW you don't need delete your answer, if you're sure about it should solve OP's issue. Maybe I'm just too cautious.)

Comment: Thanks. Thats exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function you require is NOT a macro, then you can fully qualify it.

```
class base {
      int bind(...);
}

class derived : public base {
       int bind(...);
       int someFunction();
}


int derived::someFunction()
{
      base::bind(); // call base class's implementation.
      bind();  // call derived::bind();
      ::bind();  // call global function.
}
```